# Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of the group $G$. Show that if the factor group $G/H$ is finite, and $H$ is finite, then $G$ must be finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of the group $G$. Show that if the factor group $G/H$ is finite, and $H$ is finite, then $G$ must be finite.

My attempt:

Since $G/H$ and $H$ are finite sets, we know that there are finite left cosets of $H$ in $G$, i.e., $|gH|=|H|< \infty,$ for each $g \in G$

We have that $G$ is the union of all these cosets of $H$ in $G$, and since we have finite cosets, $G$ must be finite.

Is this right?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine.

---

Alternatively, note that $[G:H]=\lvert G/H\rvert$ and $$| G|=[G:H]\lvert H\rvert.$$

Comment: But if I assume $|G| = [G:H]|H|$, isn't this a consequence of Lagrange's theorem? I mean, If I think this way I guess I'm assuming at the outset that G is finite

Comment: Not necessarily, @rafaelwbl. The fact that $$|G|=[G:H]|H|$$ holds for all cardinalities.

Comment: oh, thank you @Shaun, I didn't know that

Comment: You're welcome, @rafaelwbl.